# disable service before stopping one of the aws ec2 using bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I need to stop start multiple ec2 and run few command before and after  ,using bash on the same manage server so no need to ssh. I know how to start and stop ec2, example:

start instance:

```
#! /bin/bash
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234
```

stop instance:

```
#! /bin/bash
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234
```

I figured how to list all ec2 id by running :i.e.:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Test: Instance 1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId] --output text
```

My questions are:

1. how can I stop/start multiple ec2.
2. how can I grab a specific ec2  and run a command to disable service before stopping and enable it after ec2 started.

Comment: Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: Did you try `aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234 i-a1235 ...` ? If you used a shell parameter char it seems problematic to type such cranky ids. (i mean the `i-` part). If you want to have shortcuts or aliases for individual servers and/or groups/clusters, you should include examples of what you need. Creating and managing such aliases could turn into a problem. Good luck.

Comment: My main point is how to run a bash command on one ec2 , for example , before I stop i-12345 I need to shutdown oracle gracefully ( I usually do this: ```1) su - grid, 2) crsctl stop has```

Comment: SO how can i add command 1 and 2 from above inside my script.

Answer (score 1):

Just like:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Test: Instance 1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId] --output text
```

lists the instances on aws. The following will show the public DNS names of the instances

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Test: Instance 1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicDnsName] --output text
```

If the instances are running with no public access, the following can be run for a list of private IP addresses:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Test: Instance 1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress] --output text
```

The aws commands can then be used in a loop to process each entry:

```
for var in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Test: Instance 1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress] --output text)
do
     ssh -i somekey.pem "ec2-user@$var" ......... # Loop through each IP address and run ssh
done
for var in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Test: Instance 1" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId] --output text)
do
     aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids "$var" # Loop through each instance id and stop.
done
```

Comment: Raman thank you for replying : 
I don't need to ssh since the system that I am running the script on is on the same vpc and have access to all : 
I am stuck where I can grab one instance and run the command: "crsctl stop has" to stop oracle gracefully, then stop the instance.. To start them I can just run :
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234 i-a1235 ... (on all of them)

Comment: Just run the loop for the crsctl command then